# How do you create a procedures with my T-SQL code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi I am working on a SQL project. My professor wants us to write the code in T-SQL. I just learned T-SQL today, and now she added a whole bunch of other stuff to the requirements. Three of the requirements are create insert, update, and delete procedures. I have seen videos of some, but **I am having a tough time understanding what to do because no video has the SQL format like I do below.** How do I create a insert, update, and delete procedure?

```
CREATE TABLE Vet
(
    [VET_ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Vet_VetID PRIMARY KEY,
    [LAST_NAME] VARCHAR(20),
    [FIRST_NAME] VARCHAR(20),
    [STREET] VARCHAR(30),
    [CITY] VARCHAR(20),
    [STATE] VARCHAR(20),
    [POSTAL_CODE] VARCHAR(20),
    [SALARY] DECIMAL(8,2),
    [DEGREE] VARCHAR(20),
    [POSITION] VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Owner
(
    [OWNER_ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Owner_OwnerID PRIMARY KEY,
    [OWNER_NAME] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    [STREET] VARCHAR(30),
    [CITY] VARCHAR(20),
    [STATE] VARCHAR(20),
    [POSTAL_CODE] VARCHAR(20)

)

CREATE TABLE Pet
(
    [PET_ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Pet_PetID PRIMARY KEY,
    [PET_NAME] VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    [STREET] VARCHAR(30),
    [CITY] VARCHAR(15),
    [STATE] VARCHAR(2),
    [POSTAL_CODE] VARCHAR(5),
    [BREED] VARCHAR(20),
    [OWNER_ID] INT CONSTRAINT Fk_Pet_OwnerID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Owner(OWNER_ID)

)

CREATE TABLE Appointment
(
    [APPOINTMENT_ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Appointment_AppointmentID PRIMARY KEY,
    [APPOINTMENT_DATE] DATE,
    [VET_ID] INT  CONSTRAINT Fk_Appointment_VetID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES VET(VET_ID),
    [PET_ID] INT  CONSTRAINT Fk_Appointment_PetID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Pet(PET_ID), 
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT vet ON
INSERT INTO vet ([vet_ID],[last_name],[first_name],[street],[city],[state], [postal_code], [salary],[degree],[position]) 
VALUES (1, 'Skechley', 'Cristine', '24340 7th   Plaza', 'Pittsburgh', 'PA', '15274', 88053.30, 'Masters', 'Vet'), 
       (2, 'Fishpoole', 'Sig', '06784 Anthes Point', 'Philadelphia', 'PA', '19184', 45525.56, 'Associates', 'Receptionist'), 
       (3, 'Stother', 'Rycca', '04304 Superior Hill', 'Allentown', 'PA', '18105', 90553.37, 'Masters', 'Vet'), 
       (4, 'Scandrite', 'Kerrill', '30320 Express Crossing', 'Harrisburg', 'PA', '17126', 102553.59, 'Doctorates', 'Vet'), 
       (5, 'Glassman', 'Rhett', '33418 Tomscot Trail', 'Mc Keesport', 'PA', '15134', 56052.24, 'Bachelor', 'Management'), 
       (6, 'Gioan', 'Rab', '1 Pennsylvania Street', 'Hatfield', 'PA', '19440', 35880.76, 'Student', 'Janitor'), 
       (7, 'Patel', 'Dhruv', '24411 Jean Drive', 'Hatfield', 'PA', '19440', 42790.88, 'Student', 'Receptionist'), 
       (8, 'Smith', 'Giana', '24 Malple Street', 'Lansdale', 'PA', '19446', 35880.22, 'Student', 'Janitor'), 
       (9, 'Lopez', 'Briana', 'Orvilla', 'Allentown', 'PA', '18105', 74880.47, 'Masters', 'Vet'), 
       (10, 'Sam', 'Hector', 'Orvilla', 'Allentown', 'PA', '18105', 74880.47, 'Masters', 'Vet')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT vet OFF


SET IDENTITY_INSERT owner ON
INSERT INTO owner ([owner_ID],[owner_name],[street],[city],[state],[postal_code]) 
VALUES (11, 'Samantha Rodgers','96372 Dexter Terrace','Erie', 'PA','16510'), 
       (12,'Jenkins Tim','486 Marcy Avenue','Philadelphia','PA','19184'), 
       (13,'Smith Bobby','03781 Meadow Ridge','Erie','PA','16510'), 
       (14,'Parker Aaron','80 Marcy Place','Harrisburg','PA','17126'), 
       (15,'Gil Malcomn','239 Tony Point','Harrisburg','PA','17110'), 
       (16,'Ramsey Torrey','0778 Columbus Park','Philadelphia','PA','19178'), 
       (17,'Novak Cole','63519 Warbler Way','Pittsburgh','PA','15261'), 
       (18,'Cunningham Dylan','0728 Esch Terrace','Pittsburgh ','PA','15274'), 
       (19,'Barclay Liam','36 John Wall Parkway','Pittsburgh ','PA','15210'), 
       (20,'Perez Joseph','Hatfield Village','Hatfield','PA','19440')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT owner OFF


SET IDENTITY_INSERT Pet ON
INSERT INTO Pet ([PET_ID], [PET_NAME], [STREET], [CITY], [STATE],[POSTAL_CODE], [BREED], [OWNER_ID]) 
VALUES (21,'Jimmy','96372 Dexter Terrace','Erie', 'PA','16510','Affenpinscher',11), 
       (22,'Lily','486 Marcy Avenue','Philadelphia','PA','19184','American Bulldog',12), 
       (23,'Sally','03781 Meadow Ridge','Erie','PA','16510','American Eskimo Dog',13), 
       (24,'Joey','80 Marcy Place','Harrisburg','PA','17126','Barbet',14), 
       (25,'Rocky','239 Tony Point','Harrisburg','PA','17110','Papillon',15), 
       (26,'Daisy','0778 Columbus Park','Philadelphia','PA','19178','McNab',16), 
       (27,'Chloe','63519 Warbler Way','Pittsburgh','PA','15261','Mountain Cur',17), 
       (28,'Mike','0728 Esch Terrace','Pittsburgh ','PA','15274','Pug',18), 
       (29,'Bruno','36 John Wall Parkway','Pittsburgh ','PA','15210','Pomeranian',19), 
       (30,'Daisy','Hatfield Village','Hatfield','PA','19440','Rat Terrier',20),
       (31,'Tim','Hatfield Village','Hatfield','PA','19440','German Shepherd',20)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Pet OFF


SET IDENTITY_INSERT appointment ON
INSERT INTO appointment ([APPOINTMENT_ID],[appointment_date],[VET_ID],[PET_ID]) 
VALUES (21,'12/11/2017',1,25), 
       (30,'12/12/2017',2,26), 
       (23,'12/12/2017',1,27), 
       (29,'12/13/2017',4,23), 
       (25,'12/14/2017',5,22)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT appointment OFF
```

Comment: What you have there are statements to create new tables. Once you run those your database will have 3 tables. Sounds like your homework is to create tables then populate them with some data using an [insert](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp), modify the new data with an [update](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp), and finally remove some of the data with [delete](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp).

Comment: INSERT” STORED PROCEDURES that can be called to INSERT records into your different tables.
• “DELETE” STORED PROCEDURES that can be called to DELETE records from your different tables.
•  “UPDATE” STORED PROCEDURES that can be called to UPDATE records in your different tables.

Comment: This is what my professor posted. Did I meet the requirements? Or did I totally screw up the entire project

Comment: Your not done yet. Check out this [tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure-tutorial/) on stored procedures and this [example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2519/insert-stored-procedure-in-sql-server/) of an insert stored procedure.

Comment: Don't get fixated on the "T-" in T-SQL, by and large it is just SQL with some extra "twiddly bits" that all database vendors make unique to their product. T-SQL is similar in role, but actually quite a bit simpler than Oracle's PL/SQL or Postgres PL/pgSQL. The script above is a mere starting point for your assignment. In a previous question I gave you the link to T-SQL documentation - use it.